How to disable the installation of applications in chrome://app-settings/ using Chrome policies?
I am trying to restrict users from installing applications in Chrome. Specifically, I want to disable the option found at chrome://app-settings/. I've read that this might be possible through Chrome policies, but I am not sure how to implement this.
Can someone provide detailed steps or guidance on how to disable the installation of applications using Chrome policies?
Thank you!
https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/?policy=ExtensionInstallTypeBlocklist
Allready try this. But dont work.
